# Unable to replace one Entity with another in Core Data in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am working on an iOS application where I am using Core Data for storage.  In my store, every entity will be unique, and I'm building a function where I replace one existing entity with another that I pass in.  Here is an example of an entity that I pass:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MyDB sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];

    User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSNumber *userNumber = 12345;

    user.id = userNumber;
    user.name = @"John Doe";
    user.email = @"john@doe.net";
    user.createdDate = [NSDate date];

    [[MyDB sharedInstance] updateUser:user];
```

Inside my Core Data storage, I have an identical Entity already, except that the email address is "john@doe.com".  My update at the moment looks like this:

```
-(void)updateUser:(User *)user {

    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MyDB sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];

    // Create fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create predicate
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", user.id];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (error) {
        // handle fetch error
    } else {

        user = [[User alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

        for (User *recordToDelete in results) {

            [context deleteObject:recordToDelete];//record gets deleted here, which is fine

        }

        [context save:&error]; //this doesn't save the new entity that I passed in

        if (error) {
            // handle save error
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }


    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id=%@", 12345];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (User *testObject in items) {

        NSLog(@"ID: %@, Name: %@, Email: %@, Created Date: %@", [testObject id], [testObject name], [testObject email], [testObject createdDate]);

    }

}
```

The problem is that the above function deletes the existing record in the store, however, it fails to add the new entity that replaces it. How can I correct this?

Comment: I don't get why you can't just fetch entity, update necessary fields, than save context? No entity deletion will be needed

Comment: This is the way I have been requested to make the function.

Comment: I guess i found your mistake..

Comment: 1) You create user with id 12345, john@doe.net 2) You create fetch request for User with predicate of 'id == 12345' 3) You create empty User object (why?) 4) You delete objects that match predicate. Your created in 1 User is also deleted. 5) You save.

Comment: So you get empty user in your db... - no john@doe.net. You explicitly deleted it in step 4

Comment: So should I be passing the context into the method as well, and then use that when I use this line:  NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:originalContxt]; ?

Comment: No, just your algorithm has wrong logic. You create object (correct) than delete it (wrong). You don't want to delete object you created. If you explicitly want this algorithm, you have to: 1) save context before updateUser call 2) modify predicate so : `NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@ AND self != %@", user.id, user];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling save method on managed object context. Call save method on managedObjectContext in which you are creating new object.    `[managedObjectContext save:nil];`

Recmonded way is. First fetch object depending on number, and delete it. After that create managed object. At the end call Save on context.

Comment: Context gets saved after deletion loop. It's not a problem i guess.

Comment: make sure you are saving the context in which you are creating object.

Comment: So should I be passing the context along with the entity, and then use THAT specific context when saving the new entity?

Comment: If you are using shared context over the app that's fine. Your code is some what broken. user = [[User alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
this is not the way to create managed object. Use NSEntityDescription to create Managed object.

Answer (score 2):

Also, i think you don't clearly understand what is NSManagedObjectContext. It's something like in-memory object cache. So, if you create object in context, it is tied to context. Object has reference to context, so passing context with object is not necessary - object's context can be obtained from it. Also, contexts and objects are not thread-safe - you cannot pass managed objects between threads and use same context in different threads. Instead, you have to:
 1) Create context for every thread
2) If you need to pass something between threads, pass `object.objectId` from one thread, and in another thread do `[context objectWithID:]`. It's extremly fast, efficient and safe.